Using RangetoHtml code to copy table into email body cuts off string inside cells even after autofitting columns
I use Ron de Bruin's RangetoHTML code to copy a table into an outlook email.
I get a situation where the text within certain cells are truncated on the email, which I understand the code is supposed to do if cell contents exceed column width.
However, this happens even when I include the step to autofit columns in the RangetoHTML code.
The resulting cells seem to be the correct width. If I manually cut the table out of the email body and repaste it back into the email, the full string reappears, even though the column width remains the same.
There seems to be some error that is signalling the cell can fit less than it does when reading the data into the HTML string, telling code to hide a fragment of the string even when the whole stirng fits.
Not all columns appear to be affected, but the ones that are seem to be affected consistently.
I added a line of code to expand the columnwidth until the results stop truncating, it seems that the cell needs to be 45% wider than the string it contains before truncation ceases.
I noticed the output from rangetoHTML was defaulting to a larger font size only on the affected cells, despite the source data having the same font and size on all cells. So I tried adding a line to the RangetoHTML code to fix the font and size for the range to calibri 11, which did fix the font change between cells but not the truncation issue.
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit '''this line should ensure columnwidth is wide enough to contain string
        
    End With
    
    'adding these additional lines I can force the column width to be wide enough to when outputs stop being truncated
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Columns(i).ColumnWidth = Columns(i).ColumnWidth * 1.45
    Next i

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

I am using the following code to call the RangetoHTML code. I use variables to call the text strings contained in specific cells.
Sub SendEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh2 As Worksheet, rng As Range

EmailTo = sh2.Range("B2")
CC = sh2.Range("B3")
Subject = sh2.Range("B5")
strbody = "<body style=""font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14.5'; line-height: 1;"">" & sh2.Range("B7").Value

            On Error Resume Next
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = EmailTo
                .CC = CC
                .Subject = Subject
                .htmlbody = strbody  & RangetoHTML(rng)
                .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                .Display  'or use .send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

I've seen at least one other post online describing a similar issue, but there was no answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Can we see the resultant HTML? You may need to save the email as a webpage and then view the HTML there. Or copy to MS Word and save to web. Something like that (Outlook uses Word to render)

Does this work? I have never actually done this before. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fhw625pcklytl1bme2y59/Truncated-String-Email.htm?rlkey=wvlo80t6dynlovmhmkhfktms0&dl=0
